# Do Toad Houses and Present houses return after usage?

Tags: super-mario-3d-world

Do Toad Houses return at some point after you've used them?  And what about the special "big VS small present" houses?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. If you beat "The Great Tower of Bowser Land," they reappear.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they do.  The only houses that don't re-appear are the ones you get a stamp from.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for sure after you get a Game Over the Toad Houses and 1Up Roulette things all return at once.

It also seems like after completing the main game they might come back at certain intervals? I know for sure the Gold Bowser Train appears seemingly randomly, and the roulette reappears after finishing a level in the same world. Unsure about the toad houses though.